# iMac screen too big for Ubuntu to use

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ati, uefi, mac

Contrary to most questions, my 27" iMac is too big for Ubuntu to display on. Pre-startup messages show, but no text, no splash, and no desktop ever appears, just a black screen. I do hear the bongoes, however :S.

The iMac is Late 2009, 27-inch, 3.06 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, 16 GB 1067 MHz DDR3 RAM, ATI Radeon HD 4670 256 MB Graphics, with 1 TB HDD.

I am attempting to boot from Ubuntu 14.04 LiveUSB on an UEFI 1.X system, I believe. Please help!

PS: Can I dd and boot or does it have to be installed with a program like LiLi? I've tried both.

Comment: Please try to boot again, but this time edit the boot parameters and add `nomodeset` next to `quiet splash`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was install rEFInd (with some difficulty, I might add, due to some new settings in OS X El Capitan,) and then boot to my Live USB from the boot menu. This runs the Live mode in UEFI *-CSM* and somehow completes boot successfully.

**Warning - The mac will not shut down correctly, need force-off after about 15 seconds of shutdown sequence.**